# android : Find UPnP devices from network

Tags: android, upnp

I am making application in which i want to find the list of the UPnP devices that are connected to my network from my android application . Any idea how can i do this..

I am using the API of the cybergarage...here is the link of the repository...

https://cgupnpjava.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cgupnpjava/trunk/cyberlink/upnp-stack/src/main/java/org/cybergarage/

Any one who has work or has been working on UPnP Complianted Application development, can help me out.

Thank you

Comment: Try this link: http://www.android-dev-faq.com/2011/12/how-to-use-upnp-search-in-android.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a created an alternative Java UPnP library that also works on Android:

http://teleal.org/projects/cling/core/

A [manual chapter](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.html#chapter.Android) about Android integration, an [example application](http://www.teleal.org/projects/download/misc/), and a [video of the example application](http://www.teleal.org/weblog/New%20Cling%20beta3%20runs%20on%20Android%2021.html) are available. The example application shows how you can search and list all the UPnP devices on your network.

Comment: But clink code is written in maven java, that's I am not able to compile that code its showing some errors. How can I get rid of that one errors