# Get list of devices in local network (LAN)?

Tags: android, networking, broadcast, wireless

I'm looking for a way to find all devices (especially printers) in the local area network (LAN).

Is there are way to differentiate between printers and other devices (smartphones, laptops, computers, etc.)?

Comment: try looking at this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717332/android-find-upnp-devices-from-network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717332/android-find-upnp-devices-from-network)

Comment: Do you want to do service discovery or would you just like to see available network endpoints on the local network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you try this? http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/

JmDNS is a Java implementation of multi-cast DNS and can be used for service registration and discovery in local area networks. JmDNS is fully compatible with Apple's Bonjour.

Answer (score 1):

you should use Network Service Discovery

https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html